# Does the android device download the entire published APK?

Tags: android, apk, android-resources

I publish an app to Play Store by uploading an APK that contains resources (drawables, layouts, etc) optimised for various screen sizes and densities.

I'd like to know if as an end-user when I install the app on my device, does the entire apk gets downloaded as is, or does Google smartly removes resources that are irrelevant to the end-user's device depending on the device's screen size and/or density? If it does the smart work, what about the default "drawables" directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> does Google smartly removes resources that are irrelevant to the end-user's device depending on the device's screen size and/or density?

No. Modifying the APK would invalidate your digital signature.

Some distribution channels, like the Play Store, allow you to upload different APKs for different configurations, such as different densities or CPU architectures.

Comment: "No. Modifying the APK would invalidate your digital signature." is a good point that strikes the bell. Thanks!

Comment: @CommonsWare Play Store is showing update size 3.79 Mb, when APK size is over 5 Mb (which I've released today, one, single file properly signed). Can you explain?

Comment: @snachmsm: They have a patch mechanism that allows an update to only modify necessary files, in a way that the resulting APK is binary-compatible with the full APK (basically, they apply a binary diff), and so the digital signature is retained.

Comment: @snachmsm: See [this blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/saving-data-reducing-the-size-of-app-updates-by-65-percent.html) for details.

Answer (score 2):

It downloads the entire APK. You can target different APKs at different phone architectures, in case there's native code embedded, and you can create separate APKs to target at different device configurations according to [documentation here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html)

That documentation does prominently state

> Although we encourage you to develop and publish a single APK that supports as many device configurations as possible...

for whatever that's worth.